# How To Merge different workbooks with same structure in to one using dynamic Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple work books with one sheet each all with the same structure would like to merge these in to one workbook found some examples on the net but been unable to achieve what I want this code I have will create the merge but it only picks one column. I would like to copy the entire used range starting from a point eg "A2" have tried a couple here is what I tried the commented lines are what I have tried and did not work any suggestions welcome please

```
Sub Trymerge()
Dim FolderPath As String, Path As String, count As Integer
Dim ThisWB As String, lngFilecounter As Long
Dim wbDest As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim Filename As String, Wkb As Workbook
Dim CopyRng As Range, Dest As Range
Dim RowofCopySheet As Integer

ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

FolderPath = "H:\Staging\Testmerge"

' path = FolderPath & "\*.xls*"

'Filename = Dir(path)
Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "\*.xls*", vbNormal)
MsgBox Filename
RowofCopySheet = 11

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Do While Filename <> ""
MsgBox Filename
   count = count + 1
   If Not Filename = ThisWB Then
    Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FolderPath & "\" & Filename)
    MsgBox "working file" & Filename
   Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), Cells(Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
   'Wkb.Sheets(1).Range("A11").Select
    ' Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(RowofCopySheet, ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    'Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.count, .UsedRange.Columns.count))
    Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    CopyRng.Copy
    Dest.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Dest.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clear Clipboard
    Wkb.Close False
End If
    Filename = Dir()
Loop

' Range("Q8").Value = count
 MsgBox count & " : files found in folder"
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the script that I use to loop through a folder, copy data out of all files, and then save that data into a combined spreadsheet located elsewhere.  You'll need to change myPath to the path to your file folder, change the i variable to the range you need, and the j variable to the location/range of your combined spreadsheet.

```
Sub CombineReports()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Target Folder Path For Macro
myPath = "I:\Pricing\mt access\Tier Reports\Final Reports\"

'In Case of Cancel
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
myFile = Dir(myPath)
Do While myFile <> ""

'Set variable equal to opened workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
DoEvents

'Count rows in your spreadsheet and set range to copy
i = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A5", "N" & i).Copy

    'Combine data from each spreadsheet into one main sheet
    With Workbooks.Open("I:\Pricing\mt access\Tier Reports\Final Reports\Combined Report\CombinedTierReport.xlsx")
    DoEvents
    j = Workbooks("CombinedTierReport.xlsx").Worksheets("AllStores").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Workbooks("CombinedTierReport.xlsx").Worksheets("AllStores").Range("A" & j + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Workbooks("CombinedTierReport.xlsx").Save
    Workbooks("CombinedTierReport.xlsx").Close
    End With
    DoEvents

'Save and Close Workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
DoEvents

'Get next file name
myFile = Dir
Loop

'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
ResetSettings:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is already working you can just change your code as below:

Code you have:

```
Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), Cells(Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
```

You can make it slightly more simple by changing your copyrange:

Assuming the Column A goes to the bottom of your sheet and Assuming the first Row goes to the last Column of your sheet

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
```

With this the CopyRng will take your whole Range and not only the last column.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily merge data from all workbooks in a folder (below each other).

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

If, for some reason, you wanted to do the merge and have the data sets arranged horizontally, instead of vertically, you could use the script below.

```
Sub Basic_Example_3()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceCcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim Cnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    Cnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next
                Set sourceRange = mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A10")

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all rows then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Rows.Count >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceCcount = sourceRange.Columns.Count

                    If Cnum + SourceCcount >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough columns in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in the first row
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(1, Cnum). _
                                    Resize(, .Columns.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.cells(2, Cnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        Cnum = Cnum + SourceCcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub
```