# Consolidate data from multiple excel files to one master file

Tags: excel, vba

I've multiple  files and with data sample
All files seems the same as the file in the image

[image]
This is my master file structure
[image: Master]

this my code so for

```
   Sub Append()
'Append data from other files
 Path = "E:\NPM PahseIII\"
 Dim c As Range
  'find the second empty cell in ColA
 Set c = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
  Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
     Do While Filename <> ""
If InStr(Filename, ".") > 0 Then
     Filenamenoext = Left(Filename, InStr(Filename, ".") - 1)
End If

 c.Value = Filenamenoext
   Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)

 Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True

ThisWorkbook.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("B3:E6").Select
 Selection.Consolidate Sources:=Array("'" & Path & "[" & Filename & 
 "]Sheet1'!B3:B6")

Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

After running this code my master file become this
[image]

As from the second image we can see that only the file names are written in the master file but data is not consolidated from other files, I stuck in this issue for a full day and don't know what's wrong with my code,
Secondly i want that there should be no repeat if i run this code again then the data should not need to be duplicated is currently it's duplicating data because when i run the code again the file names are written again starting at the bottom of the previous record.
what could be the issue with my current code in order to consolidate data from other files and don't do duplication?

Comment: Have you managed to successfully use the Consolidate Excel feature without any code? That would be a first step. It won't succeed with `Data` as text values, there needs to be some numerical data to aggregate: to sum or max, etc.

Comment: Is there other way to do this task? with text data i need text data not numeric.

Comment: If it is not numeric then it what way would it be `consolidated`? If you have 3 rows of data in Workbook1, how would you shrink them down to a single row in the summary book?

Comment: I'm not shrinking it in one see my code i've selected range i want it should go in it.

Comment: have a look  here maybe you might be able to change it to your specification [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53262718/how-to-merge-different-workbooks-with-same-structure-in-to-one-using-dynamic-ran]

Comment: ? In your screenshots Workbook1's data occupies 3 rows; your master file has 1 row available labelled Workbook1. Again, how would you squeeze 3 rows into 1? What will it look like?

Comment: please have a look at the code i specified range and the last image you can see the selected range is selected by the code, Also if you know how to achieve this then share a code here.

Comment: look at these line i specified master file range here ActiveSheet.Range("B3:E6").Select
 Selection.Consolidate Sources:=Array("'" & Path & "[" & Filename & 
 "]Sheet1'!B3:B6")

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see how you get along.

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm